# How many people has Wolverine killed in the X-Men movies?

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, kill-count

How many people has Wolverine killed in the movies, starting with X-Men (2000)?

Comment: Huh? Why would this generate a "too long" list of answers?

Comment: Relatively straightforward. The only real debate was how to factor in the retcon timeline.

Comment: The total is 47 kills in movies starting with X-Men

Comment: @Huangism - Maybe I'm overthinking it, but aren't you being too simplistic? What about the whole time-travel-retcon deely?

Comment: @Richard you are over thinking it, it's a simple question

Comment: Does it make a difference where you start?

Answer (score 8):

Wolverine's death-count is actually surprisingly low, at least until you get to 'The Wolverine'.

---

**X-Men (2000)** - Logan's kill-count is **zero.**

**X-Men 2 (2003)** - Logan's kill count is **eleven.**

**X-Men 3 (2006)** - Logan's kill count is **twenty-two.**

**X-Men Origins: Wolverine (2009)** - Logan's kill count is **eleven.**

**X-Men: First Class (2011)** - Logan's kill count is **zero.**

**The Wolverine (2013)** - Logan's kill count is **fifty-four**. (!)

**X-Men: Days of Future Past (2014)** - Logan's kill count is **three.**

---

- **Caveat #1**

  - I'm basing the death count on "*fell down and didn't get up*" rather than "*absolutely dead, **no foolies***".
- **Caveat #2**

  - If you take into account *every* death seen on screen, **the total number is 90** however due to the retcon timeline, it's unclear whether we can accept any of the events of X-Men 1, 2 or 3 (and most of Wolverine, excluding the opening sequence where he kills a WWII-era German soldier) as ever having happened, limiting the total to 12.

Comment: Sources = http://www.allouttabubblegum.com/ and youtube body count videos.

Comment: Not all of those can be considered certified deaths. Some were probably just injured and maimed and could get medical help

Comment: DoFP's timeline reset throws every death after 1973 into question - why are you only making *The Last Stand*'s count optional?

Comment: Does X-Men Origins show him killing people in the intro montage? Those deaths would still be unchanged.

Comment: @phantom42  - Surprisingly, aside from kicking a WWII german soldier and "clothes-lining" a vietnam-era American GI he only appears to kill one person in the opening montage.

Comment: caveat #2 does not exist because the OP specifically asked for kill count in movies. The movie The Wolverine 2013 also does not count since it does not start with X-men as the OP specifically asked for

Comment: @Huangism "starting with X-Men" could easily refer to the *release* order of the films (which is how I first read it). Also, what do you mean "caveat #2 does not exist"? It's right there! Seriously, though, it is a legitimate note, as DoFP means that in-universe, most of the other events *didn't happen*, so we could argue that Wolverine didn't really kill anyone in the previous movies.

Comment: @KSmarts I am just being precise, it's a simple question, people are over thinking this. All you gotta go by is "killed in the movies, starting with X-Men?" I mean it's good to think about the time thing but I don't think the OP really meant that by this question

Comment: @Huangism - I think it's clear that he meant "in the present X-Men universe series". I've edited the question accordingly.

Comment: @Richard I see what you mean but there is a slight possibility that the OP did that on purpose to setup some kind of a trick question. Isn't the first one in 2000 as in your answer?